# Well-rated gtk themes that work on Loki

Tags: themes

I have a lot of GTK themes that I like and I have saved for use on various gtk desktops, like [Adapta](https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme) and other well-rated ones, but most do not work on Elementary, as stated [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/11140/170).

I see that [Ant](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1099856/) themes work.

Is there some internet resource dedicated to gtk themes for Elementary/Pantheon desktop?

---

### New answers are welcome even after the a definitive answer is confirmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- MacOS-Sierra:

> cd ~/.themes
>
> git clone https://github.com/B00merang-Project/macOS-Sierra.git

- Ant-Themes: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1099856/
- OSX-Arc- deb [here](https://github.com/LinxGem33/OSX-Arc-White/releases/download/v1.4.3/osx-arc-collection_1.4.3_amd64.deb) - requires `sudo apt install gnome-themes-standard-data gnome-themes-standard`

Source: http://e.ysfl.cn/bbs/forum.php?mod=forumdisplay&fid=41

OSX-Arc-darker:

[image]

---

**~Edits by cipricus**:

**Other GTK themes:**

- Another gtk theme (although not satisfying the exigence of being "well-rated") - [eOS-milky](http://entornosgnulinux.com/2017/05/02/elementary-theme-eos-milky-para-elementary-os-loki/). Offers transparency but somewhat clunky in other respects (quasi-black color of selection which hides the black text of the file's name).
- [Flattastic](https://nale12.deviantart.com/art/Flattastic-11-03-2014-424913255) GTK theme.
- [Numix](https://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Numix-GTK3-theme-360223962) GTK theme works too. Also, [Numix-blue](https://github.com/aceat64/Numix-Blue).

**Considering icon themes** (although that's beyond the scope of the question), they are easier to use with elementary than gtk themes, but even so most of them increase a lot the size of the panel icons (and that size is not editable). A set that doesn't do that and shows the same icon size as the default is **ePapirus**, from the [Papirus](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme) suite.

Comment: You should post content of link not just link. I will edit your answer.

Comment: Ant themes were already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in this ：https://github.com/ysfl/elementaryos

Comment: I guess these are all the gtk themes out there that can be used for elementary. I wasn't able to find others.

Comment: look this https://www.gnome-look.org/

Comment: of course, gnome-look. but one has to test them before seeing if they work. and all i have tested do not, except Ant and what you posted

Answer (score 1):

I like OSX Buttons. It keeps the same elementary style but with OSX style buttons. You just have to use elementary Tweaks to shift the windows controls to OSX style to the left.

https://github.com/yarik-vv/OS-X-buttons

[image]

Comment: I only use one, close-button, as seen in the image from main answer: in order to un-maximize I just drag the window, to minimize I use right-click on window upper margin - an option that can be enabled with: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-right-click-titlebar 'minimize'` . Unlike KDE, GTK desktops do not allow closing windows by clicking them with the mouse (like middle-mouse).

Comment: Yes thank you, if the user has not installed elementary Tweaks than editing the gsettings works just as well.

Comment: the above setting to minimize window with right-click is not present in tweaks

Comment: I guess I should post how to roll that setting back (to showing the menu): `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-right-click-titlebar 'menu'` -- as an answer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/15378/170).

Comment: That would be helpful